# Cant run roo command in Mac OSX

Tags: java, spring-roo

I have downloaded Spring Roo onto Mac OSX.  I have set a symbolic link to roo.sh in /usr/bin.  There is execute permission on the script.  But running even roo.sh in the bin folder of the raw roo installation returns "command not found".

How can running roo.sh in the bin folder where the actual roo.sh file is held not work?

Regards

i

Comment: oops...symbolic link not correct.  Working now...although still a little confused as to why running roo.sh in the bin folder directly failed to find it?

Comment: I guess Mac OSX does not put the current directory in the path by default (just like most Unix variants)